# Time to live with Meteor.Collection

Tags: meteor

does a Meteor Collection provide any way to use the [TTL](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/) (Time to live) feature from mongodb? Need this for a kind of multiuser-session with temporary data. It's not important that the changes are fully reactive.

Comment: i'm wondering this as well. I want my objects to disappear from the database after an hour.

Answer (score 0):

Two parts to this answer:

1) to apply the index you can use the _ensureIndex method in Meteor, however as the _ suggests, support for this could be pulled anytime. There may also be limitation in terms of what can be passed, but for something as simple as

```
db.log.events.ensureIndex( { "status": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 3600 } )
```

.. then the standard implementation of mongo-livedata

```
self._collection._ensureIndex(index, options);
```

... should be sufficient.

2) I haven't tested it, but I'm rather sure TTL will work. (I have on the other hand tested capped collections and they do work). You see, what DDP does in terms of picking up data changes is two fold:

- It polls mongo after every write operation that it knows meteor has driven
- It polls mongo anyway every 10 seconds (for out of bands update)

Thats second part means that you can go in your mongo shell manually, delete/add/update stuff, and the changes will be reflected no later than 10 seconds afterwards.

On that basis, if you're happy with the 10 second delay to reactivity, then TTL should work.

If you're not happy with this, you could try Arunoda's smart collections, which you can read more about on: http://meteorhacks.com/introducing-smart-collections.html. They read from the oplog (if you have one), so that might reduce the delay to reactivity. Note that this concept, while interesting, has limitations that David Glasser has covered in this post: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/meteor-talk/h-ulU7guh1Y/nTfJ1F8uGxwJ

In any case, good luck and let us know how you get on.