# How do I sign-in a server-side acquired SSO user into the Meteor Accounts package?

Tags: meteor, coffeescript, single-sign-on

Using `Meteor`, `coffeescript` and `iron-router`, I am successfully acquiring a user from a SAML Identity Provider (IdP).

How can I use these user details to sign-in the user via the Meteor Accounts package?

Consider the following server-side routes:

```
Router.route '/sso/saml2', where: 'server', name:'ssoSaml'
    .get ->
        @response.writeHead 302, 'Location': saml.getRequestUrl()
        @response.end()
    .post ->
        {secret:{password, email}, profile, state} = saml.getProfile @request.body.SAMLResponse
        user= Meteor.users.findOne {'profile.domainId': profile.domainId}
        userId = if user? then user._id else Accounts.createUser {password, email, profile}
        # I have the user id - How do I sign the user in?
        @response.writeHead 302, 'Location': "#{state.location}"
        @response.end()
```

The process is as follows:

- The GET route redirects the browser to the IdP end-point with an appropriately generated `SAMLRequest`.
- The IdP processes the `SAMLRequest` and returns a `SAMLResponse` to the POST route.
- The `SAMLResponse` is processed returning the user's `secret` fields, public `profile` and a `state`object containing the originally requested `location`
- The unique, immutable `profile.domainId` is used to retrieve the user from the Meteor `user` collection
- If no `user` exists a new one is created.

At the end of this process I have the user details and I know the user exists in the `Meteor.users` collection. To finish I need to sign-in the user and redirect to the originally requested location.

How do I sign-in the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately, the login call that sets the user must be made from client code.

1. Define a collection for login tokens:

   ```
   @LoginTokens = new Mongo.Collection 'loginTokens'
   ```
2. Use your original server-side routes, but create a one-time login token for the client to use to log in, then redirect to a client route, passing the token.

   ```
   Router.route '/sso/saml2', where: 'server', name:'ssoSaml'
       .get ->
           @response.writeHead 302, 'Location': saml.getRequestUrl()
           @response.end()
       .post ->
           {secret:{password, email}, profile, state} = saml.getProfile @request.body.SAMLResponse
           user= Meteor.users.findOne {'profile.domainId': profile.domainId}
           userId = if user? then user?._id else Accounts.createUser {password, email, profile}
           tokenId = LoginTokens.insert { userId, expires: +(new Date)+tokenExpirationInMilliseconds }
           @response.writeHead 302, 'Location': "/sso/login/#{tokenId}?loc=#{state.location}"
           @response.end()
   ```
3. Register a custom login handler on the server accepting and validating a login token:

   ```
   Accounts.registerLoginHandler ({tokenId})->
       {userId} = LoginTokens.findOne tokenId or {}
       return {userId} if userId?
   ```
4. Call this handler on the client in your client-side route that receives the login token, but make sure the arguments match this strange signature (notice the array):

   ```
   Router.route '/sso/login/:tokenId', ->
       {tokenId, query} = @params
       Accounts.callLoginMethod
           methodArguments: [{tokenId}]
           userCallback: ->
               Router.go if query?.loc? then query.loc else '/'
   ```
5. Finally, create a job on the server that regularly clears expired tokens:

   ```
   Meteor.setInterval ->
       LoginTokens.remove { expires: { $lte: +(new Date) } }
   , 1000
   ```

** Note: be sure to pass an *object* containing the login token as the element in the methodArguments array when calling your login method, Also, in the login handler, return an *object* with the `userId` property whose value is the user id for your user, in order to match the expected signatures.

Comment: You mentioned that the POST route should be running on the client. Can you show me how I can the SAMLResponse data here? On the server you can see I get it via `@request.body.SAMLResponse` but I cannot find the equivalent for a client route. Thanks.

Comment: Please see **Edit 1** above for more details.

Comment: Progress has been made I believe - thanks for your effort. Please see **Edit 2** for latest.

Comment: The data sent in the first element of the `methodArguments` array for the login method should be an object. And the login handler should accept an object. I edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Your advice and sample code got me to a working solution. Please see **Edit 3** for details. I updated the code in the original question so it better matches the final answer (minus your changes). Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Glad to help. I'd also forgotten about the CS object sugar, thanks for reminding me :-). BTW, I included an expiration date in the login token as well as a job to clear them so they don't pile up in the db.

Comment: I forgot about the expiration. I intended to see if I could a Mongo TTL index for this. Found the following: [Time to live with Meteor.Collection](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18290196/776476)

Comment: The `_ensureIndex ` command for Mongo TTL seems a bit dodgy in meteor so I tried the following, which works nicely and feels more encapsulated:
**Remove LoginToken after 1 minute**
`tokenId = LoginTokens.insert {userId}, (err, _id) -> Meteor.setTimeout (-> LoginTokens.remove _id), 60000 if _id?`